# Having an ascii character in a println statement

Tags: java

How do i print the ascii character for the degree sign when I'm writing a line of code like this:

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + (char)('z' +126) + "F --> ");
```

Apparently it's written like that, but when I run it, it seems to add the value of the char to fahrenheit rather than printing fahrenheit and degree symbol.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578738/unicode-character-for-celsius-degree

Comment: The answers that say to use a Unicode character are correct.  But note that whether it will be displayed correctly may still depend on whether the terminal you are printing to supports Unicode.  Most do, but apparently Windows CMD.EXE still doesn't, or by default uses a font that doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the char cast and the string in parentheses. This will override Java's default evaluation order, which evaluates the addition operator from left to right.

Without parentheses, Java looks at your code and thinks "Oh - two numbers! Let's add them." With parentheses, Java looks at your code and thinks "Oh - a number and a string! Concatenation time."

So, you could write something like:

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + ((char)('z' +126) + "F --> "));
```

Comment: Or `""+` at the very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you could do it with something like this,

```
int fahrenheit = 100;
System.out.println(fahrenheit + "\u00b0F --> ");
```

On my system that outputs

```
100°F -->
```

You can also use formatted output, something like,

```
System.out.printf("%d\u00b0F --> %n", fahrenheit);
```

For the same output as above.

Comment: Per Kevin's comment above, though, Unicode isn't universally supported. The use of it for this application introduces a "magic number": the average programmer would have no idea what `\u00bF` represents without a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fahrenheit` is int/double/etc you should turn it into a string:

```
System.out.println((fahrenheit + "") + (char)('z' +126) + "F --> ");
```

otherwise it is summed with `'z'+126`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "\u00B0" escape char

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + "\u00B0"); etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this very readable:

System.out.println(fahrenheit + "°F --> ");

Note: You refer to ASCII. Java uses Unicode for strings.